# What is an "observable" in reactive programming?

Tags: system.reactive, reactive-programming

Microsoft [says](https://rx.codeplex.com/), "developers represent asynchronous data streams with Observables." I'm trying to reason through the idea. If I were to tackle the concept implicitly, I would imagine that it's just, *anything that could be observed in the data stream.* Code should be more precise.

How would I know an "observable" if I saw it? Could you give me a better explanation of what an "observable" is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Microsoft says, "developers represent asynchronous data streams with
>   Observables." I'm trying to reason through the idea. If I were to
>   tackle the concept implicitly, I would imagine that it's just,
>   anything that could be observed in the data stream. Code should be
>   more precise.

The code actually is more precise. An Observable is represented by the [`IObservable<T>` interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd990377.aspx). The main job of `IObservable<T>` is to handle [`IObserver<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/dd783449.aspx)s. These two work in tandem: An `IObservable<T>` represents a stream of type `T` that can be be subscribed to. An `IObserver<T>` represents a handler that subscribes to the observable to handle those events.

There are three types of events that an observable can implicitly emit:

1. OnNext: The next instance of `T`
2. OnCompleted: A non-error (empty-message) terminator.
3. OnError: An error terminator.

However, observables don't emit these messages directly, rather they emit them only onto subscribed observers.

> How would I know an "observable" if I saw it? Could you give me a
>   better explanation of what an "observable" is?

Imagine a service that reports the latest Apple stock price. You can think of the service as an observable. To get this information, you would have to subscribe to the service. Once subscribed, the service could emit one of three messages:

1. Next most-latest stock price
2. Market closed
3. Some sort of failure (connection failure would be most typical)

You would in turn write a handler to handle these three types of messages. That handler would be an observer to the observable stream of prices.

Comment: Does it mean that an Entity/Component always have to subscribe to Events of the Observer, which itself is kind of "tracking" the scoped data (source)? _Is this the common way to implement it or are there further alternatives to the Observer Pattern?_

Answer (score 1):

[From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern):

> The observer pattern is a software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes, usually by calling one of their methods.

This definition is clear when applied to the events used in user interfaces: you observe button clicks by providing a event handler which the button calls when it is clicked. In this case, the button is an observable, which notifies a number of observers in the form of event handlers.

Applied to reactive programming, an observable is just a stream of events that you can subscribe - i.e. observe. Think of it as a pipe through which events traverse and that you can peek into. You do so by observing the stream and handling those events you are interested to. Furthermore, operations can be performed over streams - for instance merging a couple streams into a new one.

Both the publishing of events to the stream and the handling of those events - your observer which processes them - can be done asynchronously which promotes scalability.

Similar concepts are those of *messages*, *topics*, and *subscribers*: some stakeholder can publish messages to a topic, to which many different stakeholders can subscribe. Respectively, these would correspond to the events, the observable stream event, and the observers.

Microsoft uses the terms **Observer** and **Observable** while in some other reactive frameworks they may use other terms. The [Getting started](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/01_WhyRx.html) of [Introduction to Rx](http://www.introtorx.com/) can help you further clarify these concepts and the whole book is a free gem. Note that this book prefers to use the term *sequence* to refer to a stream of events.

> I would imagine that it's just, anything that could be observed in the data stream.

That's right. Actually, in Microsoft's `Rx`, the main core are just the two interfaces interfaces defining the contract between observers and observables, the rest is pretty much abstracted away.

Answer (score 0):

I think the terminology varies, but if you search for functional reactive programming papers e.g. on Google Scholar, you will find definitions of the basic concepts behavior and event. I think the following two definitions from a paper from [Functional Reactive Programming from First Principles](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.23.360&rep=rep1&type=pdf) are representative:

> Behavior is a value of type a that changes over time
>
> Event is a
>   time-ordered sequence of event occurences
>
> Intuitively, a behavior is a stream transformer: a function that takes
>   an infinite stream of sample times, and yields an infinite stream of
>   values. Similarly, an event is a stream transformer, and can be
>   thought of as a behavior where, at each time t, the event either
>   occurs or does not occur.

It seems MS fuses both into the concept of an Observable.

I think it is good to read some background papers to get the terminology. The [papers from Conal Elliott](http://conal.net/papers/icfp97/icfp97.pdf) are a good start. Or you could enlist in the [Principles of Reactive Programming](https://www.coursera.org/course/reactive) at coursera if you want a more interactive introduction.