# Flutter: I have two function for reading firebase data in my flutter app. now I want to sum two function return value in a text widget

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to sum two different firebase collection field values in my flutter app. That's why I write two functions. I can sum one collection field value but two collection field value sum in a single text widget is not working or I am not understanding how to do this..

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
    child: StreamBuilder<double?>(
      stream: getFundData(),
      builder: (context, snapshort) {
        if (snapshort.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        if (snapshort.hasData) {
          double data = snapshort.data!;
          return Center(child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("$data"),
              
            ],
          ));
        }

        return Text("data");
      },
    ),
  )),
);
```

function code

```
Stream<double> getFundData() async* {
  final result =
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Use-of-fund').get();
  double totalFundAmount = 0;
  for (var doc in result.docs) {
    totalFundAmount += doc['Amount'];
  }
  yield totalFundAmount;
}

Stream<double> getUserBalanceData() async* {
  final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('User-data').get();
  double userTotalAmount = 0;
  for (var doc in result.docs) {
    userTotalAmount += doc['Balance'];
  }
  yield userTotalAmount;
}
```

Now I want to sum **userTotalAmount** and **totalFundAmount**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [RxDart (Observable package)](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart). Specifically, use [CombineLatestStream](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/CombineLatestStream-class.html) for both `getFundData` and `getUserBalanceData`. It is there that you sum the outputs when either streams emit.

```dart
// ...

StreamBuilder<double>(
  stream: CombineLatestStream.combine2(
    getFundData(),
    getUserBalanceData(),
    (double a, double b) => a + b,
  ),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {

// ...
```

Remember that you have to install the `rxdart` package in your project. Run the following command in a terminal inside your project folder:

```bash
flutter pub add rxdart
```

Then import it at the top of the Dart file

```dart
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
```

##### Explanation

So the problem is you want to be capable of summing the results from two different streams. Mainly because StreamBuilder takes only one Stream at a
time. CombineLatestStream above from the rxdart package permits you to do this. The rxdart package provides easy ways to [Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34306813/what-is-an-observable-in-reactive-programming) in a reactive programming style. In this case, the streams are all from Firebase. And even if they weren't, you will still do something similar.

Comment: can you explain a little bit more

Comment: okay let me edit the answer

Comment: The operator '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. (Documentation)  Try adding a null check to the target ('!').   this error comes in (a, b) => a + b,

Comment: that one shouldn't be a problem, you can change a + b to a ?? 0 + b ?? 0

Comment: if I added this so many error has come. can you please explain a little bit more? like my example code

Comment: I've updated the answer to include an explanation. Follow the link of observables to understand what it is. Dart Streams are just like observables you see. Also in your code, you might want to change `.collection().get()` to [`.collection.snapshots().listen()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#dart) and return it directly instead of using async* and yield. because .listen() is the real snapshot listener that continually provides a stream and not get().